# How to set position of items in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Is possible to set the position of a CardView in a RecyclerView? The position of each item is determined by two variables in my database: x and y. [In the following example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAQeR.png), the values ​​of x and y for the two items would be:

Item 1: x = 1 y = 1
Item 2: x = 1 y = 3

RecyclerView is using a GridLayoutManager. The spanCount is 3.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the position in the data set itself then call the notifyDataSetChanged method to refresh the list. In your case you should update the position in the database first then update the data set passed to the adapter. After that notifyDataSetChanged will view the changes.